# No input/output labels when using logicparse on schemdraw

Tags: python, schemdraw

I'm trying to generate some logic circuits using Collin Delker's Schemdraw Python library. When using logicparse to generate a scheme the labels for the inputs/outputs are not showing in the final image. The code I have is as follows:

```
from schemdraw.parsing import logicparse
circuit = logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$')
circuit.draw()
```

This code generates the correct scheme but no labels whatsoever (view image below). At this point I'm not sure if this is an issue with my implementation.

[Logic Circuit Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjNP2.png)

- I tried this code on Google Colab with the same results.
- I also tried changing the format using `schemdraw.use('svg')` no luck either.

The configuration of my machine is as follows:

- macOS Monterey 12.6.5
- Python 3.11.1
- schemdraw==0.16
- pyparsing==3.0.9

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed on version 0.17 by the author ([cdelker](https://github.com/cdelker)).